# Count how many times one string appears in another one

Tags: c

I've been for more than 3 hours trying to solve this problem, but it doesn't work 100%. Please help me.

Problem:
Create a function that receives two strings (A and B) and show the number of times the word of string B appears in the A, without using any function that belong to the library.
For example:

- String A: `house houuse househousehous`
- String B: `house`

It needs to show that the word house appears 3x in string A.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <conio.h> 
#include <string.h>

void count_string_b_a(char *a, char *b){
   int i,j,k=0,size_a,size_b,equal=0,cont=0;
   size_a = strlen(a); 
   size_b = strlen(b);
   j=0;
   for(i = 0; i < size_b; i++){ 
     for(j = 0; j < size_a; j++){ 
        k=0;
        equal=0;
        for(k=0; k<size_b; k++){
           if(a[j+k] == b[i+k]) equal++;
           if(equal==size_b) cont++;
        } 
      } 
   }    
   printf("B %s appears %d times in A %s",b,cont,a);
}

int main(){
   int i;
   char a[40], b[10];
   scanf("%[^\n]s",&a); getchar();
   scanf("%[^\n]s",&b);
   count_string_b_a(a,b);
   getch();
 }
```

Comment: Why not step through the code in your debugger until you see the problem ?

Comment: *"without using any function that belong to the library"* What could possibly be the motivation for avoiding library functions explicitly designed for working with strings? If the goal is to understand how those functions work, you can investigate the source code of popular implementations, but it's arguably more important to be able to *use* them than to be able to *write* them.

Comment: Isn't `strlen()` a function in the standard library?  I have to assume you're allowed the I/O functions...But maybe the requirement is not to use any of the string search functions.  The assignment `k=0` before the `for (k = 0; ...)` loop is redundant.

Comment: One reason for not using the debugger is that the algorithm is wrong.  This is better resolved by thinking than debugging.  You have two strings, a needle and a haystack.  For each position in the haystack, you need to check whether the needle matches at the current position.  For that, you need two nested loops, not three.

Comment: I think use strstr can be easily than implement by yourself, strstr is standard function of C language.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: you need to count the matches. That's one loop. You also need to find the next match. That's another loop. Correct?

Comment: @n.m. That isn't the way I'd look at it.  See my answer...and see my comment which observes that for each position in the haystack (one loop) you need to see whether the string starting at the current position matches the needle (that's the second, inner, nested loop).  The algorithm outlined and coded is naïve; there are better algorithms available (Boyer-Moore, Knuth-Morris-Pratt, for example: see [Exact String Matching Algorithms](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/) for examples). For the examples, it probably doesn't matter; for bioinformatics on DNA, it would matter a lot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well this is my approach at this problem of calculating how many times a word appears in a certain string. A custom mystrlen() function imitates the strlen function of C. The only header file you need is stdio.h

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int mystrlen(char *s)
    {
        int length = 0;

        while(*s != '\0')
        {
            length++;
            s++;
        }
        return length;
    }

    void match(char *haystack, char* needle)
    {
            int j = 0;

            int i,counter=0;

            for(i = 0;i < mystrlen(haystack);i++)
            {

                if(haystack[i] == needle[j])
                {
                    if(j == mystrlen(needle)-1)
                    {
                        counter++;
                        j = 0;
                        continue;
                    }       
                }
                else{
                    j = 0;
                    continue;
                }
                j++;

            }
            printf("%d the counter shows",counter);
    }
    int main()
    {

        char *haystack = "house houuse househousehous";

        char *needle = "house";

        match(haystack,needle);


    }
```

Comment: Your solution is working almost 100%, i'll try to understand and find the error. For example if i write:  char *haystack = "pencil  pencil penciil pen penc pe pen55cil penci9llppencil55 pencillip peplic pencilrpencilpe"; and  char *needle = "pencil"; The counter will show 5, and should be 6. Thank you very much

Comment: The problem pattern for the `pencil` code is `ppencil`.  The code does not count that correctly.  It is also surprising to see only one explicit loop — that complicates the analysis.

Comment: The code fails when you get part way through the string: hunting `pencil` in `ppencil`, or `pepencil` or `penpencil` or `pencpencil` or `pencipencil` fails). Using `mystrlen()` in the `for` loop control is not a good idea. It means that the outer loop is quadratic in the length of the haystack. The `mystrlen()` inside the loop is less problematic, but if you use the lengths, you should precalculate them outside the loop. (`int haylen = strlen(haystack); int pinlen = strlen(needle);` or something). Or you can modify the code to check for the null byte at the end of the haystack and the needle.

Answer (score 2):

This is my simple-minded solution to the problem, using two loops as I suggested in a comment:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static
int count_occurrences(const char *haystack, const char *needle)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; haystack[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        int j;
        for (j = 0; needle[j] != '\0' && needle[j] == haystack[i+j]; j++)
            ;
        if (needle[j] == '\0')
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int main(void)
{
    {
    const char haystack[] = "house houuse househousehous";
    const char needle[] = "house";

    printf("Haystack <<%s>> vs needle <<%s>> = %d\n",
           haystack+0, needle+0, count_occurrences(haystack+0, needle+0));
    printf("Haystack <<%s>> vs needle <<%s>> = %d\n",
           haystack+1, needle+1, count_occurrences(haystack+1, needle+1));
    printf("Haystack <<%s>> vs needle <<%s>> = %d\n",
           haystack+1, needle+0, count_occurrences(haystack+1, needle+0));
    printf("Haystack <<%s>> vs needle <<%s>> = %d\n",
           haystack+1, needle+2, count_occurrences(haystack+1, needle+2));
    printf("Haystack <<%s>> vs needle <<%s>> = %d\n",
           haystack+6, needle+4, count_occurrences(haystack+6, needle+4));
    }

    {
    char *haystack = "pencil pencil penciil pen penc pe pen55cil penci9llppencil55 pencillip peplic pencilrpencilpe";
    char *needle = "pencil"; 
    printf("Haystack <<%s>> vs needle <<%s>> = %d\n",
           haystack+0, needle+0, count_occurrences(haystack+0, needle+0));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note how the calculation of the number of occurrences is done separately from the printing of the number of occurrences.  The function that reports the number of occurrences could be generally useful; a function that also prints the data is unlikely to be reusable.  Generally, separating I/O from computation is a good idea.

Sample output:

```
Haystack <<house houuse househousehous>> vs needle <<house>> = 3
Haystack <<ouse houuse househousehous>> vs needle <<ouse>> = 3
Haystack <<ouse houuse househousehous>> vs needle <<house>> = 2
Haystack <<ouse houuse househousehous>> vs needle <<use>> = 4
Haystack <<houuse househousehous>> vs needle <<e>> = 3
Haystack <<pencil pencil penciil pen penc pe pen55cil penci9llppencil55 pencillip peplic pencilrpencilpe>> vs needle <<pencil>> = 6
```

#### Better algorithms exist

The algorithm coded above is naïve; there are many better string matching algorithms available (Boyer-Moore, Knuth-Morris-Pratt, for example: see [Exact String Matching Algorithms](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/) for examples).  It does, however, work and is simple to understand. For the example strings, it probably doesn't matter; for bioinformatics and DNA fragment matching, it would matter a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(equal==size_b) cont++;
```

needs in my opinion:

```
if(equal==size_b) {cont++;equal=0;}
```

to reset your counter to find a next match.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably [read the scanf manual, carefully](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html). In fact, this goes for all standard library functions. `%[^\n]s` is not a derivative of the `%s` format specifier; It's a `%[^\n]` followed by an attempt to read (and discard) a literal `'s'` character. I suggest fixing it by removing the `s` from the end, and reading the manual before using any C standard library function for the first time. Don't forget to check the return value.

In what world are you allowed to use `strlen`, but not `strncmp`? Get rid of this:

```
 for(j = 0; j < size_a; j++){ 
    k=0;
    equal=0;
    for(k=0; k<size_b; k++){
       if(a[j+k] == b[i+k]) equal++;
       if(equal==size_b) cont++;
    } 
  }
```

Use `strncmp(&a[i], b)` to determine equality, instead. If you can't use any standard library functions in this exercise, then write your own standard-compliant `strlen` and `strncmp`, and inline them manually into your function. You might then realise that your two inner-most loops weren't doing what they were supposed to. I would suggest that this exercise you are doing is a waste of time, because it's teaching you to do things the wrong way. If you must reinvent `strncmp` and `strlen`, then do so by writing your own `strncmp` and `strlen`.

Answer (score 0):

use `strstr` like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int count_string_b_a(const char *a, const char *b){
    int count = 0;
    size_t lenb = strlen(b);
    const char *p = a;
    while(NULL != (p = strstr(p, b))){
        ++count;
        p += lenb;
    }
    return count;
}

int main(){
    int cont;
    char a[40], b[10];

    printf("A>");
    scanf("%39[^\n]", a);
    printf("B>");
    scanf(" %9[^\n]", b);
    cont = count_string_b_a(a, b);
    printf("B \"%s\" appears %d times in A \"%s\"\n", b, cont, a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: case of A:"howhowhow" B:"howhow" , count 1. shoud be 2?

Comment: Note the requirement 'without using any function that belong[s] to the library'.  Obviously, the I/O functions are from 'the library'; we can reasonably interpret it as 'no string manipulation functions from the library'.